# What do "Blas GEMM launch failed" errors from Tensorflow mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm learning tensorflow reading a korean book.
I just copied and pasted code of this book
but this code shows me error message. 
I want to find about this but even I can't see which message I should find about. 
Can anyone help me please...?

Here is the code. (using jupyter notebook)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_data = np.array(
    [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]])

y_data = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],  # 기타
    [0, 1, 0],  # 포유류
    [0, 0, 1],  # 조류
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
])

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 10], -1., 1.))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([10, 3], -1., 1.))

b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))

L1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W1), b1)
L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)

model = tf.add(tf.matmul(L1, W2), b2)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=Y, logits=model))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
```

Until here there was no error, but from below cell the code made error message.

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for step in range(100):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})

    if (step + 1) % 10 == 0:
        print(step + 1, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data}))
```

---

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(6, 2), b.shape=(2, 10), m=6, n=10, k=2
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_3, Variable/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2e54042a3fcf> in <module>
      4 
      5 for step in range(100):
----> 6     sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
      7 
      8     if (step + 1) % 10 == 0:

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(6, 2), b.shape=(2, 10), m=6, n=10, k=2
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_3, Variable/read)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 505, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1425, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 127, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 759, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1199, in inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1113, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 357, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 267, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 534, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 294, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2819, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2845, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 67, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3020, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_ast_nodes
    if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-4ad5b6dffb7c>", line 1, in <module>
    L1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W1), b1)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2122, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 4567, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\ilovemeat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(6, 2), b.shape=(2, 10), m=6, n=10, k=2
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_3, Variable/read)]]
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is...?
I wonder if the error message is hard to read so I put the picture of it here.

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMvfA.png)

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPusX.png)

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfUCU.png)

Last cell is like below. Thanks for your help...!

```
prediction = tf.argmax(model, 1)
target = tf.argmax(Y, 1)
print('prediction:', sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: x_data}))
print('real value:', sess.run(target, feed_dict={Y: y_data}))

is_correct = tf.equal(prediction, target)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))
print('accuracy: %.2f' % sess.run(accuracy * 100, feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data}))
```

Comment: As a future note -- an ideal title, instead of saying "these errors", contains enough information that someone else can recognize the problem from that title alone, without needing to click through and read question text.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I even couldn't find what the error's name was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days have passed, there was no answer so I write it down myself.
I closed all the notebooks and console prompt window, restarted jupyter notebook and it worked. 
I think the problem was about connections.